# Using integers to access a key, value pairs in a dictionary?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key, key-value

Question: how can i use integer to use as Keys for a dictionary?

Explanation:
I have a dictionary

```
example = {}
```

I am populating it with key, value pairs of

```
A: something
B: something
C: something
1: something
2: something
3: something
4: something
5: something
6: something
```

Now i need to iterate over the 1 - 6 entries of this dictionary

```
for i in range(1,6):
        if self.compare(image1, example[i])>0.8:
            return True
```

Now as the keys in original dictionary are strings, and here 'i' is in integer format, I am getting the error:

```
if self.compare(image1, example[i])>0.8:
    KeyError: 0
```

In the console window if I try to access the dictionary key with `example["1"]`, it shows me its content, but when I try to show it as `example[1]`, it shows me:

```
print example[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pydevd_comm.py", line 1080, in do_it
    result = pydevd_vars.evaluate_expression(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, self.expression, self.doExec)
  File "pydevd_vars.py", line 352, in evaluate_expression
    Exec(expression, updated_globals, frame.f_locals)
  File "pydevd_exec.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 1
```

Comment: example[str(i)]

Comment: @Alexander as you were the first to enter this. Please add this as a comment so i can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to convert the integer to a string to match your dictionary key format.

If you don't mind returning False if none of the comparisons exceed your threshold of 0.8, you could do this:

```
return any(self.compare(image1, example[str(i)]) > 0.8 for i in range(1, 6))
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the number to a string before trying to access the dictionary:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    if self.compare(image1, example[str(i)]) > 0.8:
        return True
```

Or create the dictionary using integer keys instead of strings for the keys that are numbers.